Looking for a general definition of "classical" higher-order logic in literature
By "classical," I mean merely not working within the propositions-as-types paradigm.
I have been unsuccessfully searching the internet for literature containing a general definition of higher-order logic and its inference rules. The definition of Isabelle/HOL was the closest thing I have found, but its downside is that its definition and rules of inference are presented in the somewhat cumbersome syntax of a programming language.
Below, I also outline my rough idea of the most general HOL formal system, and I would appreciate any feedback, criticism, comment etc. about it.
We start with a BNF defining types.
$$
\alpha ::= \iota \,\, | \,\, B \,\, | \,\, \alpha \to \alpha
$$
where $\iota$ denotes a basic type of individuals (there can be finitely many: $\iota_1, \dots, \iota_n$). $B$ is the unique boolean type, $B := \{ \top, \bot \}$.
The syntax of HOL is done via typing. The equality relation is a polymorphic function ${=} : \alpha \to \alpha \to B$. $n$-ary logical connectives are functions of the form $B^n \to B$. The quantifiers are polymorphic functions $\forall, \exists : (\alpha \to B) \to B$. The well-formed formulas of HOL are precisely those strings whose type type-checks to $B$.
It is not hard to encode powersets as types in this system, so that we may quantify over sets. $\wp(\iota)$ is $\iota \to B$, i.e., sets are bijectively represented by their characteristic functions. Some authors also add the basic type constructor for products, $(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)$, meant to represent $\alpha_1 \times \dots \times \alpha_n$, which I omit for the sake of simplicity. As far as I can see, the notion of product cannot be defined from other primitives, but powersets of products can: $\wp(\alpha_1 \times \dots \times \alpha_n)$ is $\alpha_1 \to \dots \to \alpha_n \to B$.
I expect that HOL's rules of inference are the standard propositional rules, coupled with quantifier rules with additional type restrictions (e.g., substitution is only allowed for the type $\alpha$ which the quantifier binds), but I am not confident in my assessment. To really understand what the inference system is doing, I also need to know HOL's semantics, and this is the reason I am looking for a solid academic reference of this (seemingly) most general formulation of HOL. Thank you for your help.

There is HOL Light, which is also a programming language, but may be clearer than Isabelle

@DanielWeber Thank you. It seems strange to me that these rules don't include rules for quantifiers, and that equality is stated to be "the only primitive notion." Does that mean that HOL can be done without quantifiers?

A quick search brings up https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/higher-order+logic+as+a+dependent+type+theory and https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.15382
